# Can't find Cross Platform App (Xamarin) in project options

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I want to create a Cross Platform App (Xamarin) but I don't see that option.  I have installed the latest version of Visual Studio.

[image]

In a Udemy course I subscribed to, the options are different. It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Please consider adding the photo directly to the question next time.

Comment: Select the "Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms)" option shown in your screen cap.

Comment: I suggest you to read the quick getting started guide. When you select Mobile app, you can proceed with the app creation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/get-started/hello-xamarin-forms/quickstart?tabs=vswin

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a native cross-platform app you can find that in the `Other` section. They seem to have moved it; I spent 2 days looking for it and never thought I would find it there

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm 5 years late though here is what the updated option is now in VScode. Now it's called a 'Mobile App (Xamarin.Froms)'[image]